# How to get rid of error codes SC1009, SC1073, SC1056, SC1072

Tags: bash

So I have put in my bash script in shell check and I'm getting this error code which says:

```
Line 61:
function print_2() {
^-- SC1009 (info): The mentioned syntax error was in this function.
                   ^-- SC1073 (error): Couldn't parse this brace group. Fix to allow more checks.

 
Line 164:
manage_users;
             ^-- SC1056 (error): Expected a '}'. If you have one, try a ; or \n in front of it.
             ^-- SC1072 (error): Missing '}'. Fix any mentioned problems and try again.
```

I'm having a hard time getting rid of the error message and finding the problem, I've tried making changes but I'm getting the same error message and I was wondering if any of you could help me find the problem.

```
    #!/usr/bin/bash


# Run script as sudo

if [ "$(id -u)" != "0" ]; then
        sudo bash "$0" "$@"
        exit
fi

# Define a function to print Network information
function print_1() {
    # Clear screen
    clear
    echo " "
    echo "-----Network information-----"
    echo " "
    # Function that displays the name of the computer, the names of all
    # network interfaces (excluding the loopback interface), their IP addresses, MAC
    # addresses, gateway addresses, and up/down statuses.

        function display_network_info() {
                # Get the name of the computer
                hostname=$(hostname)
                echo "Computer name: $hostname"

                # Get the names of all network interfaces (excluding the loopback interface)
                interfaces=$(ip link show | grep -v 'LOOPBACK' | grep -oP '(?<=: ).*(?=:)')

                # For each network interface, get its IP address, MAC address, gateway address,
                # and up/down status
                for interface in $interfaces; do
                        # Get the IP address
                        ip_address=$(ip addr show $interface | grep -oP '(?<=inet\s)\d+(\.\d+){3}')

                        # Get the MAC address
                        mac_address=$(ip link show $interface | grep -oP '(?<=link/ether\s)[0-9a-f]{2}(:[0-9a-f]{2}){5}')

                        # Get the gateway address
                        gateway_address=$(ip route | grep -oP '(?<=default via )\d+(\.\d+){3}')

                        # Get the up/down status
                        up_down_status=$(ip link show $interface | grep -oP '(?<=state\s)\w+')

                        # Print the interface information
                        echo "Interface: $interface"
                        echo "IP address: $ip_address"
                        echo "MAC address: $mac_address"
                        echo "Gateway address: $gateway_address"
                        echo "Up/down status: $up_down_status"
                        echo " "
                done
        }

# Call the display_network_info function
display_network_info

}

# Define a function to print User management menu
function print_2() {

 clear

echo " "
echo "-----User management-----"
echo " "

function manage_users() {
  # Display the menu options
  echo "1. Create user"
  echo "2. List users"
  echo "3. Change user attributes and password"
  echo "4. Remove user"
  echo "5. Back to main menu"
  echo " "

  # Prompt the user to make a selection
  read -p "Enter your selection: " selection

  # Handle the user's selection
  case $selection in
    1)
      # Prompt the user for the username and password
      read -p "Enter the username: " username
      read -p "Enter the password: " password

      # Create the user
      useradd -m $username
      echo "$username:$password" | chpasswd

      # Display a success message
      echo "User $username successfully created"
      ;;
    2)
      # Get the names of all users (excluding default and system users)
      users=$(getent passwd | grep -vE '^(root|halt|sync|shutdown|daemon|bin|sys|adm|lp|mail|uucp|news|man|proxy|www-data|backup|list|irc|gnats|nobody|systemd-network|systemd-resolve|dbus|avahi|colord|geoclue|pulse|rtkit|sshd|tss|whoopsie|_apt|lxd)' | cut -d: -f1)

      # For each user, get their attributes and group membership
      for user in $users; do
        # Get the user's attributes
        attributes=$(getent passwd $user | cut -d: -f5)
        
         groups=$(groups $user)

        # Print the user information
        echo "User: $user"
        echo "Attributes: $attributes"
        echo "Groups: $groups"
      done
      ;;
    3)
      # Prompt the user for the username
      read -p "Enter the username: " username

      # Check if the user exists
      if id -u "$username" > /dev/null 2>&1; then
        # Prompt the user for the new password
        read -p "Enter the new password: " password

        # Set the new password for the user
        echo "$username:$password" | chpasswd

        # Display a success message
        echo "Password for user $username successfully changed"
      else
        # Display an error message if the user does not exist
        echo "Error: User $username does not exist"
      fi
      ;;
    4)
      # Prompt the user for the username
      read -p "Enter the username: " username

      # Check if the user exists
      if id -u "$username" > /dev/null 2>&1; then
        # Remove the user
        userdel $username

        # Display a success message
        echo "User $username successfully removed"
      else
        # Display an error message if the user does not exist
        echo "Error: User $username does not exist"
      fi
      ;;
    5)
      # Return to the main menu
      print_2
      ;;
    *)
      # Display an error message for invalid selections
      echo "Error: Invalid selection"
      manage_users
      ;;
  esac
}

function print_2() {
  true
  # other function code goes here
}

manage_users;
```

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! Check out the [tour]. This question doesn't seem to be specific to Ubuntu; really it's about writing Bash code. That's not to say it's off-topic, but there's a site specifically about coding: [so]. **However**, on SO, you'd need to make [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), which would help catch basic mistakes like this. [Questions caused by a typo get closed there](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic). But, even if you're not posting on SO, the process of making an MRE helps.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let's take them one block at a time. First: ([SC1009](https://github.com/koalaman/shellcheck/wiki/SC1009) and [SC1073](https://github.com/koalaman/shellcheck/wiki/SC1073))

```
Line 61:
function print_2() {
^-- SC1009 (info): The mentioned syntax error was in this function.
                   ^-- SC1073 (error): Couldn't parse this brace group. Fix to allow more checks.
```

This relates to the function defined in line 61 `print_2`. Here you're missing a closing bracket `}` after the function, and before you define the next function.

So I guess it should look like this:

```bash
# Define a function to print User management menu
function print_2() {

 clear

echo " "
echo "-----User management-----"
echo " "
} # <--- REMEMBER TO ADD THIS
```

And then: ([SC1056](https://github.com/koalaman/shellcheck/wiki/SC1056) and [SC1072](https://github.com/koalaman/shellcheck/wiki/SC1072))

```
Line 164:
manage_users;
             ^-- SC1056 (error): Expected a '}'. If you have one, try a ; or \n in front of it.
             ^-- SC1072 (error): Missing '}'. Fix any mentioned problems and try again.
```

I guess these will automatically disappear when you add the aforementioned closing bracket - since the parser is still expecting one.

Also, please be aware that you have the following code at the end of the script:

```
function print_2() {
  true
  # other function code goes here
}
```

This will OVERRIDE any existing `print_2` function, so please check if this should be here at all.

*Finally, if you're doing nested functions, you should use indentation to show this. I assume the closing bracket should be where I wrote, but only you will know. Indentation will help you manage the different parts in your script, and a general tip would to make indentation consistent for better readability.*

Comment: I think OP was defining nested functions.

Comment: @Jos Judging from indentation, I don't think so. But added a comment at the end of my answer - only the OP will know.

Comment: It fixed. Thank you guys

Answer (score 4):

(not an answer to your actual question, this is a reaction to your code)

All bash functions are global, even if they are defined inside another function:

```sh
foo() { echo "this is foo"; bar() { echo "this is bar"; }; }
```

Although `bar` does not exist until you call `foo`, `bar` is not local to `foo`:

```sh
$ bar
bash: bar: command not found
$ foo
this is foo
$ bar
this is bar
```